# echarts: How to make node clickable when using svg path as symbol

Tags: svg, events, echarts

Couldn't find an answer on SO or elsewhere, so by all means, link me there :)

I've created a Graph(forced) chart, and used a SVG as symbol.
Click events only trigger if I click the SVG paths itself, they do not trigger in between the paths.

How can I wrap the symbol with a div/span/other or any other solution to make the area of the symbol clickable, wether on the SVG path or not.

Thank you!

Comment: put a rect over the whole area (or under it) and use that to capture clicks.

Comment: @RobertLongson, is that part of echarts API? I don't see a symbol formatter, Or you meant to alter the SVG somehow?

Comment: I meant alter the SVG. After all you did tag this question with that tag.